# Why fallback option from combotest package isn't working here?

Tags: fonts, mathspec

Following a comment here I'm playing with `combofont` package currently. But I have some questions about it. The first thing I would like to know is why the `fallback` option isn't working in my code. I mean, `OldStandard.otf` does not have `ligatures`, so I'm trying to fill these empty spaces with `ptm`. But, as you can see if you compile my `mwe`, it does not work. Notice that I have used `fonttable` to guess the glyphs I want to change.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{article}
\usepackage{combofont}


\usepackage{fonttable}

\setupcombofont{combotest1-italic}
 {
  {file:OldStandard-Italic.otf:\combodefaultfeat} at #1pt,
  {file:texgyretermes-italic.otf} at #1pt,
  {file:texgyretermes-italic.otf} at #1pt
 }
 {
   {} ,
  0x66,
  fallback
 }

\DeclareFontFamily{TU}{combotest1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{TU}
{combotest1}{m}{it}{<->combo*combotest1-italic}{}


 \setupcombofont{combotest2-italic}
 {
  {file:TeXGyreTermesX-Italic.otf:\combodefaultfeat} at #1pt,
  {file:OldStandard-Italic.otf} at #1pt
 }
 {
   {} ,
    0x00-0x65*0x67-0xFF
 }
 %
\DeclareFontFamily{TU}{combotest2}{}
\DeclareFontShape{TU}
{combotest2}{m}{it}{<->combo*combotest2-italic}{}


\newcommand{\abc}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz }
\newcommand{\ligs}{ff fi fff ffi fl ffl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}


\begin{document}
\centering

\xfonttable{T1}{ptm}{m}{it}

\abc \ligs

\fontfamily{combotest1}\selectfont
\textit{\abc \ligs}


\fontfamily{combotest2}\selectfont
\textit{\abc \ligs}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are defining the families combotest1 and combotest2, but you are using the undefined family combotest. I suggest that you close this mess, take a break, spent a few hours to sort out your question and come back tomorrow.

Comment: Fixed (again). It was the last mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old Standard has ligatures (with the exception of the fff-Ligature).

Imho it is a quite horrible idea to mix fonts like this. The f has clearly a different hook as the rest of the chars.

Beside this: some of the ligatures have unicode code points (due to historical reasons) and so you need to pull them into too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{combofont}

\setupcombofont{combotest1-italic}
 {
  {file:OldStandard-Italic.otf:\combodefaultfeat} at #1pt,
  {file:texgyretermes-italic.otf} at #1pt,
  {file:texgyretermes-italic.otf} at #1pt
 }
 {
   {} ,
  0x66*0xfb00-0xfb04,
  fallback
 }

\DeclareFontFamily{TU}{combotest1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{TU}
{combotest1}{m}{it}{<->combo*combotest1-italic}{}



\newcommand{\abc}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz }
\newcommand{\ligs}{ff fi fff ffi fl ffl}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}

\begin{document}

\textit{\abc  \ligs}

\fontfamily{combotest1}\selectfont
\textit{\abc \ligs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is not the 'f' but the 'i' in the fi-ligature in my opinion. So I was thinking about moving to cmr. By the, some OldStandar files have an alternative 'f'. Is it possible to use it? Because it is exactly what I want...

Comment: I don't answer new questions from comments. Ask a real new question, so that also other people see it and not only me.